# 404 Not Found fixed with downgrading spring boot version

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, http-status-code-404

I have two mappings on same url, one is POST and GET, there is also a POST method with id as path variable

```
@GetMapping("/students")
@PostMapping("/students")
@PostMapping("/students/{id}")
```

and this is my html using thymeleaf:

```
<form method="POST" th:action="@{'/students/{id}' (id=${student?.getId()})}"}>
```

In spring boot 3 when student variable is null i get error 404 not found for mapping '/students/', however when i downgrade to version 2 it works fine, any fixes for this without changing the url mappings and downgrading?

Comment: That is because there is no automatic trailing slash handling anymore. So `/students/' is a route with no matching endpoint giving an 404, while in the v2 this route is handled as if there were no trailing slash. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-mvc-and-webflux-url-matching-changes